# How to fix this bug at installing Kali nethunter on termux?

Tags: android, kali-linux

I'm trying to install nethunter but I get an error:

```
chmod: cannot access 'kali-arm64/usr/bin/sudo': No such file or directory.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are proividing to chmod is wrong. Get the path using find command.

For seaching in home:

> find ~ -type d -iname "kali-arm64"

For seaching in root:

> sudo find / -type d -iname "kali-arm64"

Or

You can use [this](https://github.com/Hax4us/Nethunter-In-Termux) script to get nethunter in termux.

Or

You can also check out this [Kali Nethunter App](http://store.nethunter.com/)